# Winning strategy of a player where the game is adding divisor to that number.

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

> Two players $A$ and $B$ move alternately by adding a proper divisor of $n$ to the current $n$. The goal is a number $\ge 1990$. Who wins if they started with $n=2$.

At first $A$ add 1 to 2 and form 3. Then $B$ add 1 to 3 and form 4. After that $A$ add 2 to 4 and form 6. This moves are necessary . From what is the winning players strategy to won this game.I just started this chapter and faced this critical (for me ) problem. Please help me.

Comment: Why can't $A$ add 1 to 4 to form 5?

Comment: Because I said proper divisor.But as 2&3 does not have any proper divisor so A & B add 1

Comment: Is 1 not a proper divisor of 4?

Comment: @Malcolm **a** proper divisor. Any one of them.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat The OP in the question implies that the move "add 2 to 4 and form 6" is forced.  "This moves are necessary".  The OP also implies this in the response to my original comment.  My reference says 1 is a proper divisor of any n>1.  The OP seems unclear.  This needs clarification prior to considering the question.  Hence my request for clarification.

Comment: @Malcolm As this question is in my text book,I also don't know which one is correct. So we can divide this in two cases where 1 is a proper divisor of any number and other case 1 is not

Comment: Does the textbook say that "add 2 to 4" is necessary? Or are you saying that on your own?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, $1$ is regarded as a proper divisor, so there are two options when choosing a move from $4$, namely to go to $5$ or $6$.

Analyzing from the perspective of the last few moves, it's apparent that:

- a win is immediately possible from any even number over $1327$
- any odd number will give an even number on the next move
- any prime number will give the subsequent number
- an even number over $885$ not divisible by $4$ can give an odd number over $1327$

and so on, giving a trail of winning positions to try to force and losing positions to avoid.

---

In fact after further assessment one winning strategy is simple; you can generally win from even numbers, so always put your opponent onto an odd number (below 3/4 of the target, for safety) until you get an even number in the immediate win range.